# Scaling issues with distributed Tensorflow and GRPC

Tags: tensorflow, grpc

I have an "embarrassingly parallel" graph that I put on N machines in my cluster using distributed Tensorflow, which are fed from a single input queue (located on one `device`) and which has results collected in a single `FIFOQueue` on one machine.

The problem is that when I start using N>24 of my machines, I get assertion failures related to GRPC (I believe), such as:

`E0810 18:27:17.823769199    4394 byte_stream.c:59]           assertion failed: stream->cursor < stream->backing_buffer->count`

and

`E0810 17:31:40.015537128   60432 parsing.c:715]              ignoring out of order new grpc_chttp2_stream request on server; last grpc_chttp2_stream id=3067, new grpc_chttp2_stream id=3063`

Are there best practices for creating graphs such that scale in terms of cluster coordination? How might I go about debugging this issue?

Comment: The gRPC core isn't supposed to assert. You may have found an actual bug there, and it would help the gRPC team if you'd [file an issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues) on the GitHub gRPC project with a code sample that can reproduce this.

Comment: Currently the project that caused this is a closed-source Tensorflow-based project, but I will be open sourcing in the next month or two. I can provide steps to reproduce at that time.

Comment: @SamWhitlock Did you solve the problem? I am going through exact same problem.

Comment: Yes. Check out @mrry's [presentation here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=la_M6bCV91M) about how to scale distributed tensorflow. Basically, each process connects to a param server and is driven by a separate Python process.

Comment: I've already watched that and have implemented the between graph replication. I am having this problem of grpc error that is mentioned in your question. More details here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13213